# Python browser game bot - How to best gather information from numbers that are displayed slightly different every time?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm learning Python and the first challenge I set myself is to program a bot for a browser game. My script requires the input of numbers that are displayed at certain positions during the game. I do this by taking a screenshot of the displayed number and comparing it to a screenshot of the same number at the same position I saved earlier on my computer. If the screenshot and the comparison image are the same, the function returns True.

This is the code I use for the comparison of screenshot and the comparison image:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops

def equal(img1,img2):
return ImageChops.difference(img1,img2).getbbox()is None

screenshot = Image.open(path)
comparisonimage= Image.open(path)

if equal(screenshot, comparisonimage) == True:
    return (20)
```

The approach above works very well for 95% of the numbers I need as input for my script. Unfortunately, there are apparently some positions where the numbers are displayed with very subtle differences every time they appear. The differences aren't noticeable with the naked eye and I can't find them even if I zoom in to see the individual pixels and compare them with each other, yet the function returns False every time I take a screenshot of the number and compare it to its comparison image.

One of my ideas to solve this issue was to compare the file size of the screenshots with the comparison image's file size, but this method is not reliable because the file sizes vary too much (another indication that there are indeed tiny differences every time the number is displayed). I have considered OCR, Mean Squared Error and Structural Similarity Measure, but all of these methods are rather complex and would probably slow down the script tremendously.

I would really like to find a simpler solution if possible. Please share any ideas with me you might have. Here are two screenshots of the same number at the same position at different times. [Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6ZOq.png) [Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YQA6.png)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: can you print the difference value of both images? Probably you can just set a very low theshold with ImageChops.difference(img1,img2).getbbox() <= thresholdNearZero

Comment: Thank you, Micka. I just experimented with this. If I print the difference of one 20 with three other 20s, I get: (0, 0, 25, 17), (0, 0, 25, 18), (0, 0, 25, 18). By comparing 34 screenshots with each individual screenshot, I found that the last number of this output is a reliable indicator if the numbers on the screenshot are the same or not. If the numbers on the screenshot are the same, the last number is between 16 and 18, otherwise it's 19. The other numbers vary a lot, depending on which screenshots I print the difference of. Do you have an idea how I could just compare the last number?

Comment: I just found out that the values in the brackets behave like a list. I think this could be the solution for my problem. Thank you again, Micka.

Comment: ah, just seen it. Are you sure you want to use the size of the difference box? Probably you wanted to use the absolute or average pixel difference in total? But nice, if you've found a solution by just regarding the size of the box :)

Comment: The size of the difference box works very well so far. Out of curiosity and for future projects: How can I actually get the absolute and average pixel difference with that function? Sorry for my noobish questions. I'm just starting out. :) Grüße aus Gütersloh!

Comment: I don't know imageChops, but it looks like ImageChops.difference(img1,img2) computes per pixel absolute difference. So probably you'll just have to average all those pixels somehow.